# How to copy web page content in a file via linux terminal?

Tags: linux

I want to copy some texts from a web page to a file in Linux. I know "wget" can be used to download files but my favourite data is not stored in files and when I want to have them, I have to use copy and paste manually which is very difficult for thousands of web pages.
For example, I need to have the data in the link below:

http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2017&MONTH=09&FROM=0112&TO=0112&STNM=72672

and similar link with varying YEAR, MONTH, FROM, TO, STNM values.
Is there any command/script to copy and paste automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

First, make a file with all of the year, month, from, to and stnm. A line for each one:

inputFile.txt:

```
2017,09,0112,0112,72672
2017,08,0112,0112,72672
```

In a shell script,loop through that file line by line and execute wget replacing your hardcoded values with variables filled from the read line:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r year month from to stnm; do
  wget "http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=$year&MONTH=$month&FROM=$from&TO=$to&STNM=$stnm"
done < inputFile.txt
```

That's the bare bones version, I'm certain it could use some tweaks to get up and running, but it should be close.

Execute the shell script:

```
bash whateveryounamedthisscript.sh
```

In this example two new files will be generated, one for September and another for August.